# Calculating the Jacobian of inverse functions

Tags: matrices, determinant

The task is this: given the following pair of functions:

\begin{cases} u = e^x cos(y) \\ v = e^x sin(y) \end{cases}

Determine the inverse functions, and compute the Jacobian of the inverse functions of these functions.

Am I understanding correctly that what the Jacobian matrix is:

\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial u^{-1}_x}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u^{-1}_y}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial v^{-1}_x}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v^{-1}_y}{\partial y} \end{bmatrix}

Comment: This exact example is given in wikipedia. You might want to check it out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

Comment: I'm sorry but Wikipedia articles on these topics are always above my level of comprehension...I see "this exact" example, but is that not merely a Jacobian matrix for the functions themselves, not for the inverses as this question asks?

Comment: *Hint:* to find the inverse, note that $u^2 + v^2 = e^{2x}$ hence $x = ...$. Similarly, $v/u = \tan(y)$ hence $y = ...$

Comment: @SimonS You should post that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to finish off what Simon S said, to get the inverse functions:

Note that $u^2+v^2=e^{2x} \rightarrow x(u,v) = \frac{\ln (u^2+v^2)}{2}$

and $\frac v u= \tan y \rightarrow y(u,v) = \arctan \frac v u$.

Now, the Jacobian is $\begin{vmatrix}
x_u & x_v \\
y_u & y_v
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
\frac{u}{u^2+v^2} & \frac{v}{u^2+v^2} \\
\frac{-u}{u^2+v^2} & \frac{v}{u^2+v^2}
\end{vmatrix} = \frac{2uv}{(u^2+v^2)^2}$

(of course there are certain restrictions on domains and ranges from the arctan and the sines and cosines but whatever)

Comment: Frankly I don't understand why people so much like to give hints in comments instead of solution in the answers. I've gone and completed the problem on my own in the meantime, however thank you anyway!